# How to find the most amount of shared characters in two strings? (Python)

Tags: python, string

```
yamxxopd
yndfyamxx

Output: 5
```

I am not quite sure how to find the number of the most amount of shared characters between two strings. For example (the strings above) the most amount of characters shared together is "yamxx" which is 5 characters long.

xx would not be a solution because that is not the most amount of shared characters. In this case the most is yamxx which is 5 characters long so the output would be 5.

I am quite new to python and stack overflow so any help would be much appreciated!

Note: They should be the same order in both strings

Comment: They should be in the same order in both strings?

Comment: You're looking for the longest matching *substring*.

Comment: yes they should be in the same order in both strings

Comment: The simplest method is just to loop over and try to match until you fail. Then report that as the length. For instance, at each position of `y n d f y a m x x`, the longest match is `1 0 1 0 5 4 3 2 1`. The maximum is `5` so you report the substring that occurs there (`y a m x x`).

Comment: For ```abcd``` and ```arcd```, will it be ```acd``` or ```cd```?

Comment: the output will be cd

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple, efficient solution using dynamic programming.

```py
def longest_subtring(X, Y):
    m,n = len(X), len(Y)
    LCSuff = [[0 for k in range(n+1)] for l in range(m+1)] 
    result = 0 
    for i in range(m + 1): 
        for j in range(n + 1): 
            if (i == 0 or j == 0): 
                LCSuff[i][j] = 0
            elif (X[i-1] == Y[j-1]): 
                LCSuff[i][j] = LCSuff[i-1][j-1] + 1
                result = max(result, LCSuff[i][j]) 
            else: 
                LCSuff[i][j] = 0
    print (result )
longest_subtring("abcd", "arcd")           # prints 2
longest_subtring("yammxdj", "nhjdyammx")   # prints 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution starts with sub-strings of longest possible lengths. If, for a certain length, there are no matching sub-strings of that length, it moves on to the next lower length. This way, it can stop at the first successful match.

```
s_1 = "yamxxopd"
s_2 = "yndfyamxx"

l_1, l_2 = len(s_1), len(s_2)

found = False
sub_length = l_1                                 # Let's start with the longest possible sub-string
while (not found) and sub_length:                # Loop, over decreasing lengths of sub-string
    for start in range(l_1 - sub_length + 1):    # Loop, over all start-positions of sub-string
        sub_str = s_1[start:(start+sub_length)]  # Get the sub-string at that start-position
        if sub_str in s_2:                       # If found a match for the sub-string, in s_2
            found = True                         # Stop trying with smaller lengths of sub-string
            break                                # Stop trying with this length of sub-string
    else:                                        # If no matches found for this length of sub-string
        sub_length -= 1                          # Let's try a smaller length for the sub-strings

print (f"Answer is {sub_length}" if found else "No common sub-string")
```

**Output:**

> Answer is 5

Answer (score 0):

```js
s1 = "yamxxopd"
s2 = "yndfyamxx"

# initializing counter
counter = 0

# creating and initializing a string without repetition
s = ""
for x in s1:
    if x not in s:
        s = s + x
for x in s:
    if x in s2:
        counter = counter + 1

# display the number of the most amount of shared characters in two strings s1 and s2
print(counter) # display 5
```